# Getting <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f6f056c2840> error

Tags: python

Hi I'm dealing with the list comprehension exercises but I got stuck in a code, and getting the error mentioned above. 
Already appreciate for the help!

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print([i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if not (i+j+k) == n)
```

Comment: what you are printing is not a list-comp but a generator expression. surround it with `[]`: `print([...])`.

Comment: That's not an error, but a representation of generator object.

Comment: Thanks, for the help now I see. But, now I have a syntax error at first for loop
But I can't see why

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print(tuple([i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if not (i+j+k) == n))
```

Comment: I understand that while creating list comprehensions using print([.....]) must be used.
Thanks for the help.